# Increment loop from a callback/listener

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

I am attempting to increment my for loops from a callback, I do not want them to increment unless an Animation has ended. I unfortunately am running into an issue where it recommends to set the variables (J, and I) to final, and then says I cannot increment them because they are enclosed.'

**What can I do to increment the i, and j variables when the onAnimationEnd is called?**

```
    public static void animateMarkerToICSNew(final Marker marker, AnimationRouteObj animationRouteObj) {
    List<CoordsTimePair> mCoordsTimePairList = animationRouteObj.getCoordsTimePairList();

    for (int i = 0; i < mCoordsTimePairList.size();) {
        CoordsTimePair mCoordsTimePair = mCoordsTimePairList.get(i);
        int timeInMS = (mCoordsTimePair.getSeconds() * 1000);
        LinkedHashSet<LatLng> latlngHashSet = mCoordsTimePair.getLatlngHashSet();
        final List<LatLng> latlngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>(latlngHashSet);
        for (int j = 0; j < latlngList.size();) {

            final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new Linear();
            latLngInterpolator.interpolate(1, marker.getPosition(), latlngList.get(j));

            TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
                @Override
                public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
                    return latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
                }
            };
            Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, latlngList.get(j));
            animator.setDuration(timeInMS);
            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                   //INCREMENT INSIDE HERE

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            animator.start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Errors I receive**
Cannot refer to the non-final local variable j defined in an enclosing scope
(This is before I declare the variable as final)

The final local variable j cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type
(This is after I assign the variable as final)

Comment: Does `i++;` and `j++;` in those areas not work for you?

Comment: No it doesn't work. I will post the errors I receive.

Answer (score 1):

you can't. Theoretically you could, but you will ended up starting n different animations, until the first one ends and increments your index. That's because the loop doesn't pause if you don't increment the index you are using in the loop. You can achieve what you want using the the method `View.post`, when `onAnimationEnd` is invoked, to post a `Runnable` which extracts the entries from Your collections and starts the next animation.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this exactly. So would I be looking to move away from For loops all together?

Comment: you don't need the loop. You can't use a loop to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as you have it set up now, this won't work. As your errors are telling you, you can't access these variables from an inner class unless they are final. What I recommend doing is taking all of the code from within your for loop and moving it into a separate method. You can then call that method with your `List<CoordsTimePair>` object and the index of the object you wish to animate. For example:

```
private void animateCoords(final List<CoordsTimePair> mCoordsTimePairList, final int i, final int j) {
    CoordsTimePair mCoordsTimePair = mCoordsTimePairList.get(i);

    // ... insert the rest of your code from the for loop

    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (j < latlngList.size() - 1)
                    animateCoords(mCoordsTimePairList, i, j + 1);
                else if (i < mCoordsTimePairList.size() - 1)
                    animateCoords(mCoordsTimePairList, i + 1, 0);
            }
```

This won't work exactly as it is now, but do you get the general idea? This way, you don't need the for loops or to increment your final variables / access non-final variables in an inner class. Your first call to this method would be `animateCoords(mCoordsTimePairList, 0, 0);`

Comment: This is working from what I can see, the only issue I am having is the markers are not jumping back and forth between many positions.

Comment: I am not working on the same issue nor read your answer, but plus one for inspiring me to switch to recursion instead of a `for-loop` when playing with asynchronous tasks.